# image size reduced after editing

Tags: android, image-manipulation

i created a new image by combining two images. but the size of the final is image is reduced to the size(resolution) of the screen. the code used is

```
    Bitmap pic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.me);
    Bitmap stat= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.static);
    Bitmap out1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(stat) ;
    Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(out1);
    comboImage.drawBitmap(map, 0, 0, null); 
    comboImage.drawBitmap(pic, 150f, 30f, null);
```

after this  i am storing the image as

```
     OutputStream os = null;
     os = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/" + "myNewFileName5.png");
     out1.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
     os.flush();
     os.close();
```

dimension of image is staic 640x480. but my final image is 320x240, which is my phones screen resolution. is it because i use Canvas?   is there any way to do this without changing the image sizes?

Answer (score 0):

Check your API version? There's an explanation at [In the onDraw() method, why does the supplied Canvas already have scale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286483/in-the-ondraw-method-why-does-the-supplied-canvas-already-have-scale) that for an API level lower than 4 the canvas has a default scaled compatibility mode as if it were targeting a G1 screen.